# Parsing json with gson with variant key value to hashmap

Tags: java, android, hashmap, gson

I am parsing a json response using Gson, however i have some key field subject to change 
like this

```
  {
  "id_item": "5248549",
  "id_unit": "10865300490",
  "available_quantity": "8",
  "title_item": "Casio G-Shock Bluetooth Connected Watch [GB-6900AB-1]",
  "is_wow_deal": "0",
  "img": "http://cf4.souqcdn.com/item/52/48/54/9/item_L_20130603124218_5248549.jpg",
  "additional_attributes": {
      "Brand": "Casio",
      "Watch Shape": "Round",
      "Band Material": "Resin",
      "Display Type": "Digital",
      "Targeted Group": "Men",
      "Type": "Casual Watch"
      },
  "price": "539.00 AED"
  }, {
  "id_item": "5124140",
  "id_unit": "19807600033",
  "available_quantity": "18",
  "title_item": "BlackBerry Q10 [English/Black]",
  "is_wow_deal": "0",
  "img": "http://cf4.souqcdn.com/item/51/24/14/0/item_L_20130604111349_5124140.jpg",
         "additional_attributes": {
              "Brand": "BlackBerry",
              "Operating System": "BlackBerry OS"
         },
         "price": "2,269.00 AED"
   },
```

the **additional_attributes** class is subject to change I am trying to map it to Hashmap so that I can iterate with for each loop;I can go for manual parsing and looping the string response .

Below is the java program I am supposing to implement however the approach is wrong , any suggestion is appreciated .

```
public class test {
public static void main(String stringagr[]) {
    String abc = "{ \"additional_attributes\": {\"Brand\":     \"Samsung\",\"Operating System\": \"Android\",\"Storage Capacity\": \"8 GB\"}}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    attributes hashMap = gson.fromJson(abc, Attributes.class);
    for (String string : hashMap.getAdditional_attributes().keySet()) {
        if (string.length() > 0) {

        }
    }

}

class Attributes {
    HashMap<String, String> additional_attributes;

    public HashMap<String, String> getAdditional_attributes() {
        return additional_attributes;
    }

    public void setAdditional_attributes(HashMap<String, String> additional_attributes) {
        this.additional_attributes = additional_attributes;
    }
}}
```

I have gone through the following approach as well

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public class test {
    public static void main(String stringagr[]) {
        String abc = "{ \"additional_attributes\": {\"Brand\":     \"Samsung\",\"Operating System\": \"Android\",\"Storage Capacity\": \"8 GB\"}}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type fooType = new TypeToken<Map<String, String>>() {
    }.getType();
    Map<String, String> map = gson.fromJson(abc, fooType);
    for (String string : map.keySet()) {
        if (string.length() > 0) {

        }
    }

}}
```

Comment: `attributes`,`test` classes name start with small letter, class name starts with capital letter.

Comment: @vipin sahu it looks like souq.com are launching there app :D

Comment: yeah right they are launching it very soon

Answer (score 1):

The JSON string (`String abc`) you're trying to parse is not valid... Try to surround it with curly brackets: `{ }` to say that it is a JSON object.

In fact, in the JSON response you show, you can see that the whole data is surrounded by `{ }`, so you can remove the other fields, but you have to keep the JSON stucture, namely:

```
{ "additional_attributes": {...} }
```

Comment: rather with [] i'd say, given that it is a list of objects.

Comment: @njzk2 no, I don't think so, the JSON response is an object (`{}`) with a field `"additional_attributes"`, so if he removes the other fields, the remaining JSON is: `{ "additional_attributes": {} }`

Comment: I have tested the response and edited and tried with TypeToken approach in the below example test still not working

Comment: @MikO : indeed, sorry, read to fast, though you were referring to the big chunk of json at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it , I was making some mistake , here is the answer

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String stringagr[]) {
    String abc = "{ \"additional_attributes\": {\"Brand\": \"Samsung\",\"Operating System\": \"Android\",\"Storage Capacity\": \"8 GB\"}}";
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    Type fooType = new TypeToken<AdditionalAttributes>() {
    }.getType();
    AdditionalAttributes  map = gson.fromJson(abc, fooType);
    for (String string : map.getAdditional_attributes().keySet()) {
        if (string.length() > 0) {

        }
    }

}
class AdditionalAttributes{
    HashMap<String, String> additional_attributes;

    public HashMap<String, String> getAdditional_attributes() {
        return additional_attributes;
    }

    public void setAdditional_attributes(HashMap<String, String> additional_attributes) {
        this.additional_attributes = additional_attributes;
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jSON structure is wrong, the right way is:

---

```
{
 "my_data":[
     {
      "id_item": "5248549",
      "id_unit": "10865300490",
      "available_quantity": "8",
      "title_item": "Casio G-Shock Bluetooth Connected Watch [GB-6900AB-1]",
      "is_wow_deal": "0",
      "img": "http://cf4.souqcdn.com/item/52/48/54/9/item_L_20130603124218_5248549.jpg",
      "additional_attributes": {
          "Brand": "Casio",
          "Watch Shape": "Round",
          "Band Material": "Resin",
          "Display Type": "Digital",
          "Targeted Group": "Men",
          "Type": "Casual Watch"
          },
      "price": "539.00 AED"
      }, {
      "id_item": "5124140",
      "id_unit": "19807600033",
      "available_quantity": "18",
      "title_item": "BlackBerry Q10 [English/Black]",
      "is_wow_deal": "0",
      "img": "http://cf4.souqcdn.com/item/51/24/14/0/item_L_20130604111349_5124140.jpg",
             "additional_attributes": {
                  "Brand": "BlackBerry",
                  "Operating System": "BlackBerry OS"
             },
             "price": "2,269.00 AED"
       }
   ]
}
```

---

You should to add:
 **"my_data":[**  on begin and finish with 
**]}**

Comment: may be the structure is misplaced dear , but my question is to map the data to HashMap so I have found the solution posted below